# the result printed to screen and writen to file are different

Tags: python, file, screen

```
# coding=utf-8
def compare(arr1, arr2):
arr1 = arr1.strip()
arr2 = arr2.strip()
arr1 = arr1.split('\t')
arr2 = arr2.split('\t')
# print arr1[0], arr1[1]
arr1min = min(long(arr1[0]), long(arr1[1]))
arr1max = max(long(arr1[0]), long(arr1[1]))
arr2min = min(long(arr2[0]), long(arr2[1]))
arr2max = max(long(arr2[0]), long(arr2[1]))
# print arr1max, arr2max, arr1min, arr1min
if (arr1min < arr2min):
    return -1
elif (arr1min > arr2min):
    return 1
else:
    if (arr1max < arr2max):
        return -1
    elif (arr1max > arr2max):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
f = open('er1000000new.txt')
fwrite = open('erzhesorted.txt', 'w')
lines = f.readlines()
lines.sort(compare)
for line in lines:
    # fwrite.write(str(line)) 
    print line
f.close()
fwrite.close()
```

the compare is custom sort function.

for example, when the result printed on screen, the result is

```
752555452697747457\t752551879448547328\t1468258301659\n
752563934733873152\t752561055289577472\t1468260508664\n
```

but the result printed on file is

```
6782762\t12\t1468248110665\n
2660899225\t12\t1468229395665\n
```

The two results are different, why?

Comment: did it help? if not please provide more details about what you're trying to do and how you're processing it i.e. what is `sort(compare)`, what are the content of your files?

Answer (score 0):

The `wb` option when you open a file, makes python waiting for a byte object to write in that file.
Your (commented) line `fwrite.write(str(line))` sends a string object. 
Doesn't it produce the following error?

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Also it may come from your `compare` attribute in sort method. 
What is it?

→ Removing the `b` option and removing the `compare` attribute produces the same outputs in term and file outputs.